# Creating Database with Linq 2 SQL: Column Sizes

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I use Linq2Sql to create a database:

```
[Database]
public class SqlData : DataContext
{
   public Table<JustATable> MyTable;
   public SqlData(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
   {
      CreateDatabase();
   }
}

[Table(Name = "atable")]
public class JustATable
{
   [Column]
   public int Id;
   [Column]
   public string Street;
   [Column]
   public string Name;
}
```

The Database and the table are created as wanted. All the string-Columns are created as `nvarchar(4000)`.

Is there a Property so I can reduce the field size to something different like

```
Street nvarchar(50)
Name nvarchar(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The [`ColumnAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supports it:

```
[Column(DBType = "nvarchar(50) NOT NULL")]
public string Street;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `[Column]` attribute with `[Column(DbType="nvarchar(<size>) NOT NULL")]`

`<size>` = desired length of the column.